# ListView with rows - Warnings and Errors

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm making an "infinite list" in which each index has a row with 2 cards. I'd like to make these cards the same size with their context centered. So both card have a width of totalWidth/2 - padding. But I'm not getting the wanted result, this is was my initial code:

```
new ListView.builder(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    itemExtent: 20.0,
    itemCount: gameList == null ? 2 : gameList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      if (index == 0) {
        return new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text("Click me!"),
          onPressed: () => getGames(),
        );
      } else if (index == 1) {
        return new Text("For new games");
      }
      return new Container(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Card(
              child: new Container(
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(gameList[index*2]["name"])
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Card(
              child: new Container(
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(gameList[index*2+1]["name"])
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  )
```

That resulted in an unwanted visual result and an exception!
Screenshot:
[image]

Exception:

```
I/flutter ( 3907): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY         
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3907): The following RangeError was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 3907): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..49,     inclusive: 50
I/flutter ( 3907): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 3907): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:151)
I/flutter ( 3907): #1      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure>     (/data/user/0/com.yourcompany.gamerel/cache/gamerelyjhxqR/gamerel/lib/pages/home.dart:63:42)
I/flutter ( 3907): #2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:153:33)
I/flutter ( 3907): #3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:578:67)
I/flutter ( 3907): #4      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:131)
I/flutter ( 3907): #5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:578:26)
I/flutter ( 3907): #6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:591:55)
I/flutter ( 3907): #7      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2122:19)
I/flutter ( 3907): #8      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:584:11)
I/flutter ( 3907): #9      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:282:21)
I/flutter ( 3907): #10     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1937:58)
I/flutter ( 3907): #11     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1035:15)
I/flutter ( 3907): #12     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1937:13)
I/flutter ( 3907): #13     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:280:5)
I/flutter ( 3907): #14     RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:166:17)
I/flutter ( 3907): #15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1841:7)
I/flutter ( 3907): #16     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:144:11)
I/flutter ( 3907): #17     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1841:7)
I/flutter ( 3907): #18     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:248:13)
I/flutter ( 3907): #19     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:882:12)
I/flutter ( 3907): #20     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:806:20)
I/flutter ( 3907): #21     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1718:7)
I/flutter ( 3907): #22     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1013:18)
I/flutter ( 3907): #23     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:251:19)
I/flutter ( 3907): #24     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:504:22)
I/flutter ( 3907): #25     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:189:5)
I/flutter ( 3907): #26     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:688:15)
I/flutter ( 3907): #27     BindingBase&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:636:9)
I/flutter ( 3907): #28     _drawFrame (file:///b/build/slave/Linux_Engine/build/src/flutter/lib/ui/hooks.dart:70)
I/flutter ( 3907): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter ( 3907):   RenderSliverFixedExtentList#1052375964 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT
I/flutter ( 3907):   creator: SliverFixedExtentList ← SliverPadding ← Viewport ← _ScrollableScope ←
I/flutter ( 3907):   IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#486177627] ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 3907):   RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#659063110] ← RepaintBoundary ←
I/flutter ( 3907):   CustomPaint ← RepaintBoundary ← NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 3907):   parentData: paintOffset=Offset(8.0, 8.0) (can use size)
I/flutter ( 3907):   constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.down, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle,
I/flutter ( 3907):   scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 595.4,     crossAxisExtent: 395.4, viewportMainAxisExtent:
I/flutter ( 3907):   603.4)
I/flutter ( 3907):   geometry: SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: 40.0, paintExtent: 40.0, maxPaintExtent: 40.0, )
I/flutter ( 3907):   currently live children: 0 to 24
I/flutter ( 3907): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up         to depth 5):
I/flutter ( 3907):   RenderRepaintBoundary#570038827
I/flutter ( 3907):     RenderConstrainedBox#1050372064
I/flutter ( 3907):       RenderPhysicalModel#158413069
I/flutter ( 3907):         _RenderInkFeatures#87489842
I/flutter ( 3907):           RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#431076252
I/flutter ( 3907):   RenderRepaintBoundary#551737634
I/flutter ( 3907):     RenderParagraph#594209207
I/flutter ( 3907):   RenderRepaintBoundary#766780884 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):     RenderFlex#923777135 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):       RenderPadding#893943236 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):         RenderPhysicalModel#618413979 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):           _RenderInkFeatures#994799987 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):       RenderPadding#698030940 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):         RenderPhysicalModel#956372272 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):           _RenderInkFeatures#434036791 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):   RenderRepaintBoundary#824949616 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):     RenderFlex#1033781722 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):       RenderPadding#207370496 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):         RenderPhysicalModel#1008320253 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):           _RenderInkFeatures#1069811468 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):       RenderPadding#206866148 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):         RenderPhysicalModel#533018794 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):           _RenderInkFeatures#262521214 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):   RenderRepaintBoundary#853196269 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):     RenderFlex#475430551 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):       RenderPadding#416695211 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):         RenderPhysicalModel#930790456 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907):           _RenderInkFeatures#644301116 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 3907): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I tried using CrossAxisAlignment.stretch in the column in the card but that also resulted in an exception:

```
I/flutter ( 3907): The following RangeError was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 3907): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..49, inclusive: 50
```

Note that that isn't the full exception, but this post would get way too long if I'd post that as well. But I'll post it if you need it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Column` and `Row`, you can use an `Expanded` to achieve a regular spacing of the cards. However, I think you should probably use [`GridView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.count.html) with a `crossAxisCount` of `2`, because it's a specialized class for efficiently laying out grids of boxes.

Code for both approaches below.

[image: screenshot]

Using `GridView`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

List gameList = new List.generate(100, (int index) {
  return {
    'name': 'Game $index',
  };
});

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  getGames() {
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("GridView example"),
      ),
      body: new GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3.0,
        ),
        itemCount: gameList.length,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Card(
            child: new Container(
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text(gameList[index]["name"]),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using `Row` and `Column` with `Expanded`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

List gameList = new List.generate(100, (int index) {
  return {
    'name': 'Game $index',
  };
});

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  getGames() {
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Row and Column example"),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        itemExtent: 50.0,
        itemCount: (gameList.length / 2).ceil(),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int row) {
          return new Container(
            child: new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: new List.generate(2, (int column) {
                return new Expanded(
                  child: new Card(
                    child: new Container(
                      child: new Center(
                        child: new Text(gameList[row * 2 + column]["name"]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Collin, just a few more questions:
- Can you add some sort of header to the gridview? So for example at the top of the list a widget that takes up the complete width.
- In the listview example you use List.generate but I'm confused about the "int column" param. Is column first going to be 0 and create the first card and after that 2 and create the second card?

Comment: 1. No. You can put things on top of it with a Column. But if you want them to scroll, SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount isn't the right choice. You might be able to write your own grid delegate, or use the columns-and-rows approach. 2. The column integer will be either 0 or 1

Comment: Got it! But I still got the problem with the listview approach. The cards are displayed way to small, just like in the picture in the initial post. There is no red border any more though.

Comment: Increase your itemExtent. 20.0 is too small.